# OSMDroid waypoints

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

I am working on a project with OSMDroid and I need to implement a directions feature.
My problem is that the way I'm looking for the next waypoint is not really good. 
If anyone knows a good method to do this please do not hesitate to use the answer section.
Thanks.

Comment: Need more information. what's the problem? calculating the next point or visualizing it?

Comment: Here is the situation. When I am on the road and for example I abandon it and after that reenter on a different point I need to know to that new point which waypoint is the closest one.